# What happen when "retain" NSArray or NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, nsarray, retain

In the source codes

```
@property(retain) NSString* str;
@sythesize str;
self.str = newStr;
```

I understand actually following will happen

```
if( str != newStr ){
     [str release];
     str = [newStr retain]; 
}
```

So how about the case for NSArray or NSMutableArray ? Seem like it is complex,shallow copy and deep copy should be considered.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same. Setting a property only changes the ownership of that array, not the content of the array (the content is owned by the same array). Therefore, only the array needs to be `-retain`'ed.

In fact, the runtime doesn't care about the specific Objective-C type of the property. The same setter procedure will be applied to every `@property(retain)` properties.

To make the setter perform shallow copying, make it `@property(copy)`. There no way to make it deep-copy.